# Excel to Index Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have the following spreadsheet. I have not been able to figure out how to get  the desired output which is highlighted in yellow. How would I go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The array formula `=INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(ROW(B$2:B$5)+(100*(B$2:B$5="")), ROW($A1)))&""` enter with Control-Alt-Enter, drag down as required.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

In B8, copied across right to D8 and all copied down :

```
=IFERROR("Category "&INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$5)/(B$2:B$5<>""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]